# Python pandas selecting subset of dataframe using filter condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame as below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1HwY.png)
I want to query on the columns to find out all the columns that contain 'X' for each Name.

sample output be like: (John, O, P) here O and P are the column ids against John that have the character 'X'.
I tried query on Dataframe on columns using loc, but didn't get the output. please guide to get the required output.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proposition using [**`pandas.DataFrame.apply`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and [**`dict`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) to return a dictionnary where the keys are the person names and the values are the columns names that fulfill the condition (is equal to `"X"`)

```
dico= dict(zip(df["Name"], df.eq("X").apply(lambda x: x.index[x].tolist(), axis=1)))
```

##### # Output :

```
print(dico)

{'John': ['O', 'P'], 'Dave': ['M', 'P']}
```